# Flip dimensions of a 2-dimensional list (or list of lists), where each sublist has equal length

Tags: algorithm, list, recursion, f#

I have a list of lists, where each inner list has the same length, and I need to project that as its inverse (that is, I need the dimensions flipped).

In other words, take the first item of each sublist and put that in a new list, take the second item of each sublist and put it in a new list etc. Then return a list of all these new lists.

Example: if input is:

```
let ls = [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9];[0;0;0]];;
```

Then output is supposed to be:

```
val it : int list list = [[1; 4; 7; 0]; [2; 5; 8; 0]; [3; 6; 9; 0]]
```

I have working code, but it doesn't feel right. It traverses multiple times over the lists, needs to do a `List.rev` multiple times and has to check for empty on the inner lists:

```
let rec getInnerHeads acc skipped lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> List.rev acc, List.rev skipped
    | item::rest ->
        match item with
        | [] -> [], skipped
        | innerHead::skip1 ->
            getInnerHeads (innerHead::acc) (skip1::skipped) rest

let rec flipDimensions acc lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> acc |> List.rev
    | z when (z |> List.forall List.isEmpty) -> acc |> List.rev
    | rest ->
        let (elem, skip1Elems) = getInnerHeads [] [] rest
        flipDimensions (elem::acc) skip1Elems
```

The only upside of above code is that it is rail-recursive (at least I think it is).

Anybody has a more efficient, or succinct, or both algorithm? I checked F# Snippets and SO, figured this would've been asked before, it seems so common, but I didn't find any examples.

Maybe something with `List.unfold`?

Comment: Interestingly, I just found that it already exists as `List.transpose`, which does exactly the above (though it operates on sequences for the inner lists, which might be detrimental to performance, but my above code isn't that good anyway).

Comment: Your problem is certainly more suited using Arrays rather than Lists. List.transpose, however, seems as optimized as it could be: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L742-L751

Comment: @nilekirk, thanks, it does looks rather optimized. However, as I noticed based on @gileCAD's answer and my own `List.unfold` version (see comments there), it turns out that the Core's `List.transpose` is only slightly faster on small inputs, but on large ones, the recursive one in the answer, and my `List.unfold` outperform the F# Core's one by a large percentage (1.4s vs 2.4s on certain inputs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let transpose matrix =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | (_::_)::_ as m -> loop (List.map List.head m :: acc) (List.map List.tail m)
        | _ -> List.rev acc
    loop [] matrix
```

Comment: +1. No idea why someone downvoted your solution, maybe because you didn't explain it? It is pretty concise and it uses the patterns that I failed to find (though it doesn't fail on too large inputs, but my solutions didn't fail on that either). Meanwhile (before I realized `List.transpose` existed to do this), I used a `List.unfold` version, which is as follows: `let transp = List.unfold (fun ls -> match List.head ls with [] -> None | _ -> Some ((ls |> List.map List.head), (ls |> List.map List.tail)))` (it has the same drawbacks as yours and the original)

Comment: Out of curiosity, I wondered if there's any difference in performance. So I ran all three (`Seq.unfold`, your tail-recursive loop, and `Seq.transpose`) and it turns out that on small lists, performances are nearly equal (depending on when GC collections occur). But on very large lists (5 sublists of 1M items), `unfold` ran in 1.51s, yours in 1.45s and the F# Core one (`List.transpose`) in 2.4s (!!!). All are mean lowest numbers, that is, sometimes a Gen2 occurs and it can add a whole second to each of these runs.